# Selecting multiple collections & all objects inside them

Tags: collections, outliner

It is possible to right click in the outliner on the collection > select objects. I would also like to select all my objects from another collection. Right clicking and > select objects automatically deselects my previously selected objects. Is there a way to select multiple collections and their content?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the outliner select your first collection, Right-click and 'Select Objects'.
THEN, Ctrl-click the second collection (Previous selected objects should remain selected), Right-click and 'Select Objects' again.
Now all objects from both should be selected.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer!! And is simple and worked perfectly. Thank you !!

Answer (score 2):

YES.

Create a new collection.

Drag-drop the other collections inside it.

Right-click top collection --> Select Objects.

(confirmed.)

Comment: What if your scene hierarchy doesn't allow moving collections into a new parent collection to select them all? How to select multiple collections that can't be inside a collection?

Comment: Instead of drag-dropping collections, it's better to create a new tmp collection, and linking (shift + m) to it all objects we want to select in once ; this allow to not mess up our hierarchy.

Comment: Is this really the only way to do this?  It seems like there should be  a better way!